# Using EclipseLink MOXy as JAXB provider for JAX-WS on JBoss EAP 6.1

Tags: jboss, jaxb, jax-ws, eclipselink, moxy

I'm trying to use EclipseLink MOXy as JAXB provider for JAX-WS web-service deployed on JBoss EAP 6.1.0.Beta1 application server. For now I've implemented `javax.xml.ws.Provider` as described [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/02/leveraging-moxy-in-your-web-service-via.html) and placed `jaxb.properties` file into packages containing my `Provider` implementation and domain classes used in the web-service. Here is a content of this file:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

When I try to deploy web-application containing the service I have the following error in log:

```
@XmlValue is not allowed on a class that derives another class
```

The main reason to use MOXy as JAXB-provider in my case is to be able to use `@XmlValue` annotation in subclasses. This error doesn't occure when I try to unmarshall with the same classes as used for the web-service in a test application using MOXy. Furthermore , there are no classes from `org.eclipse.persistence` package and its subpackages in a stacktrace, only `com.sun.xml.bind.v2` classes instead. Apparently, MOXy isn't used when the web-application being deployed. All required Maven artifacts from `org.eclipse.persistence` is in WAR-file:

```
$ jar tf my-app.war | grep org.eclipse.persistence
WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.5.0.jar
WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.5.0.jar
WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.5.0.jar
WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.5.0.jar
```

What am I doing wrong? As far as I understand, `Provider` is called in runtime when web-service is invoked. But the error occurs in deploy time. Should I reimplement something in addition to `Provider`?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to ensure that the EclipseLink libraries are in the correct place.  Instead of configuring MOXy as the JAXB provider can you try using the MOXy APIs directly?

```java
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] {Foo.class, Bar.class}), null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be unable to use custom JAXB provider with ApacheCXF 2.6.6 which is used as JAX-WS provider in JBoss EAP 6.1.0.Beta1. Context factory instantiating JAXBContext is hardcoded to instantiate `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory` in ApacheCXF (see `createContext` static method of `JAXBContextCache` class in ApacheCXF source code).

**UPD**: sorry for the wrong answer. There IS a way to use MOXy as JAXB provider in ApacheCXF powered web-services. For example:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;
...

@ServiceMode(Service.Mode.PAYLOAD)
@WebServiceProvider(
        portName = "...",
        serviceName = "...",
        targetNamespace = "...",
        wsdlLocation = "..."
)
public class MyService implements Provider<Source>{

    private JAXBContext jaxbContext;

    public MyService() {
        try {
            this.jaxbContext = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[]{
                    ...
            }, null);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new WebServiceException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Source invoke(Source request) {
        try {
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = this.jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            ...
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new WebServiceException(e);
        }
    }
}
```